# In how many ways can the letters of the word 'arrange' be arranged if the two r's and the two a's do not occur together?

Tags: permutations

In how many ways can the letters of the word 'arrange' be arranged if the two r's and the two a's do not occur together?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: This is not a valid arrangement: `aangrre`. But what about `aanrgre`, is this valid or invalid? In other words, do you want to exclude only arrangements where **both** letters occur together, or also arrangements where either one of the letters occurs together?

Answer (score 3):

Total number of combinations: $\dbinom{7}{2}\cdot\dbinom{5}{2}\cdot\dbinom{3}{1}\cdot\dbinom{2}{1}\cdot\dbinom{1}{1}=1260$

Number of combinations with `aa`: $\dbinom{6}{2}\cdot\dbinom{4}{1}\cdot\dbinom{3}{1}\cdot\dbinom{2}{1}\cdot\dbinom{1}{1}=360$

Number of combinations with `rr`: $\dbinom{6}{2}\cdot\dbinom{4}{1}\cdot\dbinom{3}{1}=360$

Number of combinations with `aa` and `rr`: $\dbinom{5}{1}\cdot\dbinom{4}{1}\cdot\dbinom{3}{1}\cdot\dbinom{2}{1}\cdot\dbinom{1}{1}=120$

So the number of combinations without `aa` or `rr` is $1260-360-360+120=660$